# How can I use 20 lines of HTML code in PHP without breaking up the PHP tags (<?php ?>)?

Tags: php, html, tags

I wanted to create a form and some other HTML inside some PHP code but without breaking up the tags.

Example:

```
function paypal() {
  // HTML code
}
```

So is there a way I can use a block of HTML code in PHP?

Comment: You should post more information and/or context about this including what you have tried.

Comment: you can write HTML code inside .PHP file...Do some research on the web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

For example, as an alternative to this:

```
if ($something) { ?>
<div>
</div>
<?php }
```

You can do this:

```
if ($something) {
    echo <<<HTML
    <div>
    </div>
    HTML;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, I saw someone doing just that earlier today. Here's an example solution using heredoc syntax:

```
echo <<<ENDFLAG
... some text/html here ...
... more lines of HTML ...
ENDFLAG;
```

`ENDFLAG` can be anything. Here's more info: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/2/6/3

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing what you are trying to is change something like this:

```
<?php //some php code here ?>
<p>Some html code here</p>
<br>
<p>Some html code here</p>
<?php //some other php code here ?>
etc...
```

You can just do

```
<?php 
    //some php code here
    echo '<p>Some html code here</p>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<p>Some html code here</p>';
    //some other php code here 
?>
```

Your function can do the same...

```
<?php
    function paypal() {
        //Do some fancy php
        $i = 'paypal';
        $retVal = '<p>' . $i . '</p>';

        return $retVal;
    };

    echo paypal();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `echo`, just put all the lines after an `echo` and it will work perfectly. example :

```
<?php echo ' <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>';
?>
```

Comment: It's not recommended though, as you may have to escape your quote marks (depending on which you use in PHP and HTML) and your IDE will, in most cases, no longer recognise the structure of your HTML. Thus syntax colouration, code folding and nesting validation will no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    //your php code
    echo '<html></html'; //your html code
?>
```

But it's very bad way to use html code in php with echo.

I recommend you to use html templates (mustache - https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php)